# Why is this color so different in Texture Paint, and how would I change it?

Tags: color, texture-paint-mode

In the [Donut tutorial, v4, Part 5 on Shading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsLO1F5x7yM&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEPv5y--4MKpciLaoQYZB1Z), after we set up the nodes in the shader, we switch to Texture Paint, set the base color to a new image texture, and then use the color picker to set its color. I used the numeric values that I had previously set for the donut, but the resulting color is very different.

Here is the original color that I set for the donut:
[image]

Here is the color picker in Texture Paint set with the same numeric values:
[image]

And here is the donut in Texture Paint set with that color, after clicking "OK" in the previous picture:
[image]

I have two questions:

- Why are the two colors set with the same numeric values so different?
- After clicking "OK" in the second picture above, I don't see a place pull up that color picker again to change the color. How do I change the color of the image texture named "Donut base"?

Comment: Well, the reason for this behavior is well explained in the answer by @MrA - and if you are wondering why Andrew gets a quite similar color both times without using Hex values: other than you is he not entering values at all. He is picking the color from the color picker circle and adjusts the brightness slider on the right. If you pick both colors in the same area, depending on how good you target it this results in the same/similar color. However when you look at your screenshots, although entering the same values, the dots on the circle and the slider are in quite different positions.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - I mentioned your comment at the end of a long follow-up to the first part of Mr A's answer. I'd be interested if you have any further comment about that: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306310/how-to-understand-these-color-transformations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are the two colors set with the same numeric values so different?

I believe the color picker is using linear space while the texture is using sRGB. If you want the two colors to be consistent, use the Hex value instead. It is gamma corrected.

[image: Hex]

> After clicking "OK" in the second picture above, I don't see a place pull up that color picker again to change the color. How do I change the color of the image texture named "Donut base"?

1. In the Image Editor or the UV Editor, select the generated image from the dropdown.
2. Open the sidebar by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>, and click the *Image* tab.
3. Find the color picker.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering both parts of the question. For the second part, unfortunately, that "Image" tab is greyed out for me, and I've posted a follow-up about that at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306311/why-is-this-form-for-entering-image-data-greyed-out . Please let me know if you have a solution to that. I've also posted a follow-up to the first part of your answer, but it's more theoretical and less urgent: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306310/how-to-understand-these-color-transformations .