# Why is this form for entering image data greyed out?

Tags: image, texture-painting

This is a follow-up to an answer to my previous question, [*Why is this color so different in Texture Paint, and how would I change it?*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306288/why-is-this-color-so-different-in-texture-paint-and-how-would-i-change-it/). That question had two parts, as indicated in the title. Both parts were [answered by "Mr A"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306288/why-is-this-color-so-different-in-texture-paint-and-how-would-i-change-it/#306292). This question is a follow-up to his answer to the second part, *How can I change this color in Texture Paint?*

His answer told me that in the Image Editor, I should select the generated image texture that contains the color, then open its properties by typing "N", then go to the "Image" tab to find the color picker. I did all that, and I found the color field that should allow me to open the color picker, but that field and the rest of the "Image" tab are all greyed out:

[image]

Why is it greyed out and what do I need to do to activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is greyed out because you have changed something in the image (which is also indicated by the asterisk behind the word: *Image** in the top menu).

To regain access to the settings you have to either *Save* or *Discard* the changes which are the still available options in the side panel.

**//EDIT:** I just realized my explanation is a bit misunderstandable. If you want to regain the possibility of setting the options like before when creating a **new** image, you have to click *Discard*. Because the greyed out properties are the ones to set up a completely new image, with the color as base/background color filling the complete image, and you can even change the size again.

If you click on *Save* to create an image file from what you have there, then the settings in the side panel change to settings applicable for existing images - the same which you would see as if you did not create this as new image in Blender, but simply opened any image file from your drive.

[image: unsaved image]

Comment: Ah, yes, I had misspelled the name as "Donit base". I corrected that in the Properties Editor, and that change then showed up in the Image Editor. Following your instructions, when I clicked on "Save", that just offered to let me save a file "Donut base.png" on my computer, so that didn't seem to be what I needed. Then I clicked on "Discard". The data entry fields became active, and the spelling of the name did not revert to the incorrect value. I was then able to change the color, and when I did that, the change also showed up in the viewport. So thank you for solving this problem.

Comment: Ha, a minute later, going back to the tutorial, I see that Andrew has now instructed me to save the image file on my computer. So I guess that "Save" option wold have worked as well.

Comment: @NewSites Well, it would not work exactly the same. I edited my answer to clarify the difference.